# Amazon S3 Upload Whats does Key do

Tags: file-upload, amazon-s3

I am really confused as to what the key value should be when using amazon s3 here is my code.

```
   <form action="http://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" name="key" value="{filename}" />
<input type="text" name="acl" value="public-read" />
<input type="text" name="content-type" value="text/plain" />
<input type="hidden" name="AWSAccessKeyId" value="Amazon Key" />
<input type="hidden" name="policy" value="ewogICJleHBpcmF0aW9uIjogIjIwMTItMDEtMDFUMTI6MDA6MDAuMDAwWiIsCiAgImNvbmRpdGlvbnMiOiBbCiAgICB7ImJ1Y2tldCI6ICJpcIHsiYWNsIjogInB1YmxpYy1yZWFkIiB9LAogICAgWyJlcSIsICIka2V5IiwgIntmaWxlbmFtZX0iXSwKICAgIFsic3RhcnRzLXdpdGgiLCAiJENvbnRlbnQtVHlwZSIsICJ0ZXh0LyJdLAogIF0KfQo=" />
<input type="hidden" name="signature" value="fGWi1jKU+hKZKbCIL1eD0=" />
<input name="file" type="file" />
<input name="submit" value="Upload" type="submit" />
</form>
```

Ok so i am using this service to generate my policy etc because i havent got a clue how to do this manually.

http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/s3-example-code/post/post_sample.html

This works and gives me everything to upload. But when i upload my files they are always call {filename} and not the actually filename says picture.jpg. I know this is down to this line.

```
<input type="text" name="key" value="{filename}" />
```

I want it to take that value off the actually filename i am uploading.

What am i doing wrong very confused.

I have tried leaving it blank but i get this error.

> InvalidArgumentUser key must have a
>   length greater than 0

I want it to work this out for me????

Any Help Please

Comment: I had similar problem and I solved it like [THIS][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17623622/2155074

Answer (score 9):

*I know you posted this question a long time ago, but someone might have the same question.*

**Key** is the name and path of the file you are uploading.

You can set conditions in you policy regarding the key, like what it should start with.
You can keep original file name by using the value: ${filename} (You are missing the $)

**Example**:
Keep original file name, but put in folder /docs/

The form:

```
<form action="http://yourbucketname.s3.amazonaws.com" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" name="key" value="docs/${filename}" />
<input type="text" name="acl" value="public-read" />
<input type="text" name="content-type" value="text/plain" />
<input type="hidden" name="AWSAccessKeyId" value="<YourPublicKey>" />
<input type="hidden" name="policy" value="<Base64_encoded_your_policy>" />
<input type="hidden" name="signature" value="<HMAC SHA-1 of the policy>" />
<input name="file" type="file" />
<input name="submit" value="Upload" type="submit" />
</form>
```

The policy as JSON

```
{"expiration": "2013-12-01T12:00:00.000Z",
"conditions": [
{"acl": "public-read-write" },
{"bucket": "yourbucketname" },
["starts-with", "$key", "docs/"],
["starts-with", "$Content-Type", "text/plain"],
]
}
```

What you need to do:

- Replace Yourbucketname in the for action and Policy-Json
- [Base64](http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp) encode the policy
- Set policy in form policy value
- Replace your [AWSAccessKeyId](https://portal.aws.amazon.com/gp/aws/securityCredentials) in the form
- Sign the encoded policy with your [Secret Access Key](https://portal.aws.amazon.com/gp/aws/securityCredentials) using [HMAC SHA-1](http://hash.online-convert.com/sha1-generator)
- Set signature in the form signature value

Answer (score 3):

The parameter "key" is the name of the uploaded file in the bucket. You can put different name of browsed file.

Answer (score 2):

You're just missing a $ sign in front of the {filename} bit.  It should be:

```
<input type="text" name="key" value="${filename}" />
```

See http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HTTPPOSTForms.html for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You need to take the name of the uploaded file and stick it in place of {filename}

Comment: Hi i have tried that using <?php echo $_FILES['file']['name']; ?> but nothing shows up how would you suggest doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Something I haven't seen mentioned before is to use a utility class provided by the Amazon EC2 API. The following class contains methods to get the policy string and signature. This is a great helper class if you don't need to set extra meta fields or the storage class:

```
com.amazonaws.services.ec2.util.S3UploadPolicy
```

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to do it using form based HTML upload: This [article](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1434/) does a good job explaining how it is possible. After reading the [article](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1434/) you can use my scripts mentioned below to make life easier.

Here is a python script I use for generating my policy, its signature and base64 string.

> **IMP:** Make sure the policy.json file is in the same directory

```
import base64
import hmac, hashlib
import os
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'Your Access Key'

os.system('clear')
print "This policy generator is for key : " + AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY  
print "Make sure this is the correct key."
print "IMP: Please be consistent with the file policy.json small changes in space or newline can fail policy"

policy_document = file("policy.json",'rb').read()
policy = base64.b64encode(policy_document)
signature = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, policy, hashlib.sha1).digest())

print
print "Policy (BASE64_POLICY to be inserted in HTML):-"
print policy
print
print "Signature:-"
print signature
print
```

And here is the corresponding policy.json file I use:

```
{
  "expiration": "2014-01-01T00:00:00.00Z",
  "conditions": [
    {"bucket": "BUCKET NAME" },
    ["starts-with", "$key", "PREFIX_IF_ANY"],
    {"acl": "public-read" },
    {"success_action_redirect": "http://REDIRECTED_URL" },
    ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", "CONTENT_TYPE"],
    ["content-length-range", 0, 1048576],
  ]
}
```

The HTML form for this code is as such:

```
<html> 
    <head>
        <title>S3 POST Form</title> 
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    </head>

    <body> 
        <form action="http://BUCKET_NAME.s3.amazonaws.com/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="hidden" name="key" value="picbum/${filename}">
            <input type="hidden" name="AWSAccessKeyId" value="AccessID"> 
            <input type="hidden" name="acl" value="public-read"> 
            <input type="hidden" name="success_action_redirect" value="http://REDIRECTED_URL">
            <!-- Fill these HTML fields with data generated from python script -->
            <input type="hidden" name="policy" value='BASE64_POLICY'>
            <input type="hidden" name="signature" value="SIGNATURE_GENERATED">
            <input type="hidden" name="Content-Type" value="CONTENT_TYPE">
            <!-- Include any additional input fields here -->

            File to upload to S3: 
            <input name="file" type="file"> 
            <br> 
            <input type="submit" value="Upload File to S3"> 
        </form> 
    </body>
</html>
```