# Extra Input fields in AmazonS3 Direct Upload POST Form

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have added an extra "title" field in my POST form and created a "title" attribute in my model. After the video has been uploaded the server is directed to another controller. This is done by setting the redirect field in the policy file. Now how can I access the title field in the redirected controller?

The POST form :

```
<form action="@Model.FileUploadModel.FormAction" method="@Model.FileUploadModel.FormMethod" enctype="@Model.FileUploadModel.FormEnclosureType" >

                     <input type="hidden" name="key" value="@Model.FileUploadModel.FileId" /> 
                     <input type="hidden" name="AWSAccessKeyId" value="@Model.FileUploadModel.AWSAccessKey" /> 
                     <input type="hidden" name="acl" value="@Model.FileUploadModel.Acl" /> 
                     <input type="hidden" name="policy" value="@Model.FileUploadModel.Base64EncodedPolicy" /> 
                     <input type="hidden" name="signature" value="@Model.FileUploadModel.Signature" /> 
                     <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="@Model.FileUploadModel.RedirectUrl" /> 
                     <div class="row">  
                            **<label for="Title" style="padding-right: 5px;">Title (optional) </label>
                            <input type="text" name="Title"  style="width: 200px;" />**
                     </div>
                     <div class="row_clear"></div>
                     <div class="row">
                             <input type="file" name="file" size="100" id="file"/> 
                     </div>
               </form>
```

and my FileUploadModel

```
    public FileUploadModel(string publicKey, string privateKey, string bucketName, string redirectUrl)
    {
        myPrivateKey = privateKey;

        FormAction = string.Format("https://{0}.s3.amazonaws.com/", bucketName);
        FormMethod = "post";
        FormEnclosureType = "multipart/form-data";
        Bucket = bucketName;
        FileId = "u5/i/" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString(); 
        AWSAccessKey = publicKey;
        Acl = "private"; 

      RedirectUrl = redirectUrl;
    }
    public string FormAction { get; private set; }
    public string FormMethod { get; private set; }
    public string FormEnclosureType { get; private set; } 
    public string Bucket { get; private set; }
    public string Acl { get; private set; }
    public string Policy { get; private set; }
    public string FileId { get; private set; }
    public string AWSAccessKey { get; private set; }
    public string RedirectUrl { get; private set; }
    [Display(Name = "Title (optional)")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "File")]
    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
    public int? Page { get; set; }
    public string SearchString { get; set; }

}
```

}

Here is the link I referred for creating policy form.

[Link](http://codeonaboat.wordpress.com/2011/04/22/uploading-a-file-to-amazon-s3-using-an-asp-net-mvc-application-directly-from-the-users-browser/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked around the problem by sending the title attribute through the URL.

In my RouteConfig file I added a new route:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Transcode",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{title}/{id}",
                defaults: new
                {
                    controller = "Videos",
                    action = "Transcode",
                    id = UrlParameter.Optional
                }
            );
```

and then in the Transcode action I added a title parameter. Then finally the value I passed to the redirect URL attribute was: " http://dev.area.local/Videos/Transcode/title"